# How to show all commits between HEAD and origin/master (or latest mutual ancestor)

Tags: bash, git, colors, grep

What I expect, is a git command that shows me all commits starting with `HEAD` and going back to `origin/master` to the latest mutual ancestor.

Sometimes this works quite well:

```
git log --oneline origin/master^..HEAD
```

So well that it even stops right at the last mutual ancestor if `HEAD` does not go back directly to `origin/master`.

But many times it randomly does not work as expected and the amount of lines go even further after the line of `origin/master` (the behavior usually changes after `git fetch`).

My solution is this workaround:

```
git log --pretty=format:'%C(auto)%h %C(magenta)%cd %C(blue)%an%C(auto)%d %C(reset)%s' origin/master^..HEAD | grep --color=always -B 1000 'origin/master'
```

But I don't like it for 2 reasons:

1. It forces me to not use `--oneline` which I really want to keep using for it's colors (`grep` does not work well with `--oneline`, the result of grep with `--oneline` is no output at all, maybe because of `--oneline`'s colors, not sure).
2. Using grep makes me lose all coloring, despite using `--colors=always` it has no effect at all so I end up with a colorless output.
3. Although I can imagine no useful flow in which I need a value other than `1000`, it bothers me that I'm putting there a constant, the command line should not have to use a constant to achieve what I want.

(my grep version is `3.4`, my git version is `2.25.1`)

Comment: Using `origin/master..HEAD` should show revisions that are part of tbe history of HEAD that are _not_ part of origin/master.

Comment: oh I see what you're saying, so my mistake was adding the `^` after `origin/master`. but what if I want to include in the output just the one single commit of `origin/master` as well and not more commits below it?

Comment: I could use this:
`git log --oneline origin/master.. ; git log --oneline origin/master -1
`

But it will only grant me the correct output if `HEAD` is rebased on top of `origin/master`, in case of only a mutual ancestor existing, this will add the `origin/master` line needlessly, and I don't want to add complex logic for that simple one-liner to avoid that.

Also, I would really like to understand why `^` result in including more than a single commit.

Comment: Perhaps you might want to take a look at `git ref-list`. `git ref-list HEAD ^origin/master`. It has a few funky options you might want to explore: `git help ref-list`

Comment: @eftshift0 are you thinking of `git rev-list`?

Comment: Damn it. Right. The reflex from `reflog`. `git rev-list` it is, @torek.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
git log --graph --oneline --ancestry-path origin/master^..HEAD
```

`--ancestry-path` will select only commits that are both parents of `HEAD` *and* descendants of `origin/master^`, so commits coming from a branch merged at `origin/master`, for example, will be ignored.

You can also try to skip the `^` after `origin/master`, and add `--boundary` :

```
git log --graph --oneline --ancestry-path --boundary origin/master..HEAD
```